# Should databases be dumped to SQL format or custom archive?

Tags: postgresql, restore, recovery, dump

I am wondering, what is the industry standard regarding dump formats, when making and storing the database dumps?

Is it better to dump it to a custom-format compressed and unreadable archive, or just simply .sql?

---

This is database-agnostic question, but here are examples for PostgreSQL to give the idea:

```
# MYDATABASE to CUSTOM ARCHIVE
pg_dump -Fc mydatabase > mydatabase.dump
```

vs.

```
# MYDATABASE to SQL
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres pagila > mydatabase.sql
```

Comment: There is no "industry standard"; one uses the format that's most appropriate for the use case.

Comment: I was just wondering what is typically used by people. Or how to choose the appropriate format... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself the same question that you ask whenever you need to store *any* Data:

> How are you going to *use* this <strike>Data</strike> Backup?

If you need to get "into" the file and manipulate it (as a Developer might in order to restore *part* of a dump into a Test database) then something text-based is an obvious choice.
If the database is terabytes in size, then a custom, compressed format might be more appropriate.

Please bear in mind that **backups**, in themselves, are ***not*** important.
(Yes, I *really did* say that).

What *matters* is that you can **recover** the database ...   and backups are a really *good* way of supporting that.

For straight-line speed of recovery, pg_basebackup - or something based on it - should be your *first* choice.  Whilst pg_dump produces a portable, Logical "copy" of [part of] the database, using the output from pg_basebackup will be much, *much* faster.